# Where should static files middleware be in the ASP.NET Core pipeline?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1. I thought the static files middleware should come before the mvc middleware - no need to run a request through mvc just to serve a `css` file for example.

So I have them in this order:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(/*...*/)
app.UseHsts();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute(/*...*/);
// and lastly:
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMvc(/*...*/);
```

However when I turn on debug level logging, I notice that if a static file is missing, it runs through `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware` and says `Request did not match any routes`, then runs my `ErrorController` and issues a 404 for that request.

So:

- is this the correct order for the pipeline?
- is there a way to avoid all this, or is it by design? e.g. Some "lighter" process to trigger a 404 without going through all that? Like maybe having static files middleware be first (not sure if that's wise/secure though)?

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look at the official documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x ? It should add some insight to your concerns.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks, yes I read that

Comment: Have you tried changing the order to see what happens?

Comment: @Brad I want to deal with this professionally, not using trial and error. I've already hinted in my answer that the fact that pipeline is shown in so many tutorials is prpbably (I'm guessing) because it's the most secure. I'm not sure what the ramifications of putting stuff before the security middleware will be. GEtting security right is hard, so I'm here to learn from people with the relevant experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this the correct order for the pipeline?

Yes, it is.

> However when I turn on debug level logging, I notice that if a static file is missing, it runs through `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware` and says `Request did not match any routes`, then runs my ErrorController and issues a 404 for that request. Why?

First, your missing static file request is going through exception handler, HSTS, HTTPS redirection and StatusCodePagesWithReExecute middleware, but let's ignore them, because there is nothing interesting. Request just passes through them.

Then, it is processed by static files middleware. The middleware soon understands, that file is missing and just lets your request **run to next middleware**, which is MVC middlware.

MVC middleware looks through its route table and finds "catchAll" route and lets `ErrorController` process the request. That is the reason why missing files are processed by `ErrorController`.

P.S. I suppose you have "catchAll" route something like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            .... // your routes here

            routes.MapRoute("catchAll", "{*.}", new { controller = "Error", action = "Error404" }
        });
```

Comment: So is that how you would set up your pipeline? You would not put staticfiles first?

Comment: No, static files middleware is logically on its place. I mean you can rearrange middlewares as you wish. But if static middleware is the very first in pipeline and exception occurs inside it, your app won't know about exception, because `app.UseExceptionHandler` middleware won't have ability to process exception. The same for `app.UseHttpsRedirection` middleware: we want our app process only secure requests (even to static files), so there is sense first check that request uses https schema and then let static files middleware run.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I want the security before staticfiles middleware.

Answer (score 1):

To get it lighter you can have a custom middleware something like this:

```
var avoidFolders = new string[] { "js", "css" };

app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    if (avoidFolders.Contains(context.Request.Path.Value.Trim('/')))
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
    else await next();
});
```

Although you will have to include every static folder in the array, it makes sure to directly return a 404 without proceeding to routing.